# How can i make a translucent material on Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm trying to make a translucent material on Cycles but still i'm not very experienced with nodes....i want to make a solid color that is still translucent or can receive some light on the borders, for example, like this image:

It's like organic, but translucent at the same time.

[image]

Or as a more realistic reference, like this:

[image]

Which kind of material will be the best option in order to make this?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a subsurface scattering (SSS) shader (rather than a translucent shader) mixed with a diffuse/glossy shader mix (or whatever you are using for the base surface shader).

SSS basically makes the rays scatter when they hit the surface of an object, meaning the rays don't come off the surface at the same place they hit it.  The amount of scattering is determined by the scattering radius multiplied by the scale value on the shader.  SSS is usually used for organic things such as skin.

You can check out [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22972/what-does-the-radius-vector-do-on-an-sss-shader) and [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22998/what-units-does-the-cycles-sss-scattering-radius-use) and [the documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Shaders) to learn more about SSS.